# pivot a dataframe by diagonals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

**Given a DataFrame**

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9
```

How get something like this:

```
         0    1    2
               
0      1.0  2.0  3.0
1      5.0  4.0  7.0
2      9.0  6.0  NaN
3      NaN  8.0  NaN
```

---

if we consider the dataframe as an array of indices `i, j` then in diag n would be those where **`abs (i-j) = n`**

a plus would be to be able to choose the order:

**intercale = True ,first_diag = 'left'**

```
         0    1    2
               
0      1.0  2.0  3.0
1      5.0  4.0  7.0
2      9.0  6.0  NaN
3      NaN  8.0  NaN
```

**intercalate = False, first_diag ='left'**

```
         0    1    2
               
0      1.0  2.0  3.0
1      5.0  6.0  7.0
2      9.0  4.0  NaN
3      NaN  8.0  NaN
```

**intercalate = True, first_diag ='right'**

```
         0    1    2
               
0      1.0  4.0  7.0
1      5.0  2.0  3.0
2      9.0  8.0  NaN
3      NaN  6.0  NaN
```

**intercalate = False, first_diag ='right'**

```
         0    1    2
               
0      1.0  4.0  7.0
1      5.0  8.0  3.0
2      9.0  2.0  NaN
3      NaN  6.0  NaN
```

there could even be another degree of freedom to sort by choosing the direction from the lower corner to the upper corner or the other way around. Or select the other main diagonal

**My approach with pandas**

```
df2 = df.reset_index().melt('index').assign(variable = lambda x: x.variable.factorize()[0])
df2['diag'] = df2['index'].sub(df2['variable']).abs()
new_df = (df2.assign(index = df2.groupby('diag').cumcount())
             .pivot_table(index = 'index',columns = 'diag',values = 'value'))
print(new_df)
diag     0    1    2
index               
0      1.0  2.0  3.0
1      5.0  4.0  7.0
2      9.0  6.0  NaN
3      NaN  8.0  NaN
```

I was wondering if there could be any easier way to do this, maybe with numpy

Comment: can you explain the question taking one or two example of how you get the output?

Comment: Does the order matter in each col of output, like if the col-2 of output were `[4, 2, 8, 6]` instead, would that be ok?

Comment: look at the dataframe as a 3x3 matrix, in column 0 are the values ​​of the central diagonal, in column 1 are the values ​​of the adjacent diagonals, and so on

Comment: got that, diagonals would have i - j = 0, so that would come up at 0th column, for 2 5 6 7 values, i - j =1, so they got pulled into column 1

Comment: This is not entirely important, but a plus would be to be able to choose the order, note that here it is not only ascending or descending in the direction of the diagonal. @Divakar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Case #1 : Order of elements in each column of output isn't important

**Approach #1 :** Here's one way with NumPy -

```
def diagonalize(a): # input is array and output is df
    n = len(a)    
    r = np.arange(n)

    idx = np.abs(r[:,None]-r)
    lens = np.r_[n,np.arange(2*n-2,0,-2)]
    split_idx = lens.cumsum()

    b = a.flat[idx.ravel().argsort()]
    v = np.split(b,split_idx[:-1])
    return pd.DataFrame(v).T
```

Sample run -

```
In [110]: df
Out[110]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4
1     5     6     7     8
2     9    10    11    12
3    13    14    15    16

In [111]: diagonalize(df.to_numpy(copy=False))
Out[111]: 
      0     1     2     3
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
1   6.0   5.0   8.0  13.0
2  11.0   7.0   9.0   NaN
3  16.0  10.0  14.0   NaN
4   NaN  12.0   NaN   NaN
5   NaN  15.0   NaN   NaN
```

**Approach #2 :** Similar to earlier, but completely NumPy based and no-loops -

```
def diagonalize_v2(a): # input, outputs are arrays
    # Setup params
    n = len(a)    
    r = np.arange(n)

    # Get indices based on "diagonalization" (distance off diagonal)
    idx = np.abs(r[:,None]-r)
    lens = np.r_[n,np.arange(2*n-2,0,-2)]

    # Values in the order of "diagonalization"
    b = a.flat[idx.ravel().argsort()]

    # Get a mask for the final o/p where elements are to be assigned
    mask = np.arange(lens.max())[:,None]<lens

    # Setup o/p and assign
    out = np.full(mask.shape,np.nan)
    out.T[mask.T] = b
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])

In [3]: diagonalize_v2(a)
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  5.,  8., 13.],
       [11.,  7.,  9., nan],
       [16., 10., 14., nan],
       [nan, 12., nan, nan],
       [nan, 15., nan, nan]])
```

---

#### Case #2 : Order of elements in each column matters

We have two additional input args to manage the order. The solution would a modified version inspired mostly by `Approach #1` -

```
def diagonalize_generic(a, intercale = True ,first_diag = 'left'):
    # Setup params
    n = len(a)    
    r = np.arange(n)

    # Get indices based on "diagonalization" (distance off diagonal)
    idx = np.abs(r[:,None]-r)
    lens = np.r_[n,np.arange(2*n-2,0,-2)]

    if first_diag=='left':
        w = np.triu(np.ones(n, dtype=int))
    elif first_diag=='right':
        w = np.tril(np.ones(n, dtype=int))
    else:
        raise Exception('Wrong first_diag value!')

    order = np.lexsort(np.c_[w.ravel(),idx.ravel()].T)

    split_idx = lens.cumsum()
    o_split = np.split(order,split_idx[:-1])

    f = a.flat

    if intercale==1:
        v = [f[o_split[0]]] + [f[o.reshape(2,-1).ravel('F')] for o in o_split[1:]]
    else:
        v = [f[o] for o in o_split]
    return pd.DataFrame(v).T
```

**Sample run**

Input as array :

```
In [53]: a
Out[53]: 
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Different scenarios :

```
In [54]: diagonalize_generic(a, intercale = True, first_diag = 'left')
Out[54]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  5.0  4.0  7.0
2  9.0  6.0  NaN
3  NaN  8.0  NaN

In [55]: diagonalize_generic(a, intercale = False, first_diag = 'left')
Out[55]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  5.0  6.0  7.0
2  9.0  4.0  NaN
3  NaN  8.0  NaN

In [56]: diagonalize_generic(a, intercale = True, first_diag = 'right')
Out[56]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  4.0  7.0
1  5.0  2.0  3.0
2  9.0  8.0  NaN
3  NaN  6.0  NaN

In [57]: diagonalize_generic(a, intercale = False, first_diag = 'right')
Out[57]: 
     0    1    2
0  1.0  4.0  7.0
1  5.0  8.0  3.0
2  9.0  2.0  NaN
3  NaN  6.0  NaN
```

Comment: I expected numpy to be much faster, but really the difference is a lot, nice solution sir